# Resolve a function at the end of a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

I wonder if I can add an `unlink` function inside the resolve of a promise

```
import { unlink } from 'fs/promises';
import { createReadStream } from 'fs';
import csv from 'csv-parser';

const keywords = [];

const collectKeywords = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    createReadStream(file)
      .pipe(csv({ headers: false }))
      .on('data', (data) => {
        if (Object.values(data).length) {
          keywords.push(...Object.values(data));
        }
      })
      .on('error', (error) => reject(error))
      .on('end', () => {
        unlink(file);
        resolve();
      })
  )
}
```

It works both ways:

```
.on('end', () => {
  unlink(file) ; 
  resolve();
})
```

```
.on('end', () => {
  resolve(unlink(file));
})
```

But I wonder why

Answer (score 0):

When you call `resolve(unlink(file))` it will immediately call `unlink(file)`—which returns a `Promise`—and you then call `resolve(…)` with that `Promise`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am afraid it does not clear much, as is what does the other thing do?

Comment: because the value of the `resolve(...)` doesn't seem to matter.. and javascript evaluates the arguments before calling a function

Comment: In both instances you are calling `unlink(file)`, so the file is removed. `unlink(file)` itself returns a Promise. In the first instance you just ignore that Promise and carry on with your execution while the deletion happens _“in the background”_. In the second instance you call `resolve()` with that Promise. If you  `await collectKeywords()` then in the second version you will actually wait until the file is deleted because it will chain and await the Promise you `resolve()`d with.